# Tizen Template is not showing in Tizen IDE new Project?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I downloaded **Tizen SDK** Manager and installed Tizen SDK for Native Application Development like below Image.

[image]

Now it is not showing Application Template for Tizen, however it is installed and showing in Template folder

[image]

Folder has Native Template

[image]

How to add Template in IDE?

Thanks

Comment: What is the Tizen SDK version?

Answer (score 0):

Open the update manager and select the advanced button. Then install the SDK tools.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should download the latest version of Tizen.

Comment: Why? Was there a bug in an older version? How do you know he is not using the latest version?